# Translation help for a short sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, words

> まじでおまえに愛される気しかねぇんだけど(男です)

This is a sentence I saw below a YouTube Japanese music video.

As I understand it, it says "To be honest, I only want to be loved by you (But I'm a boy)"

But that sounds so weird. Is my translation correct? And while we are at it, what grammatical function does the 気 have?

Comment: You're translation doesn't really match. Couldn't you provide the source?

Comment: As I said, it is from a music video. I would be surprised if the source helped you but sure: https://youtu.be/X3y8XKm3jn4

Comment: It's not from a music video. It's a YouTube comment. Sourcing references for context is kinda 当たり前 if you want a reliable answer, not to mention catching mistaken transliterations that happen occasionally. This comment is in reference to the lyric at 1:45.

Comment: I still dont get what the translation would be liike to English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @BJCUAI pointed out in the comment,

> まじでおまえに愛される気しかねぇんだけど(男です)

is intended to be a creative reply referring to a line of the lyrics in the video:

> まじで僕に愛される気あんの？

which is already an untypical, creative wording. 気あんの is the contraction of 気（が）ある "be willing to" + の？ (question), but 気がある usually means that you have active desire to do something, while 愛される is passive (in grammar and meaning), that means, these two phrases are not really connectable in the usual sense. It should be instead understood by adjusting grammar to the meaning, such as:

> Do you seriously want me to love you (or not)!?

On this basis, the original comment would be like:

> You know I seriously want nothing but you to love me... Note: I'm a guy

What the poster wants to say is that he likes his song very much, and this kind of "I love your video, marry me" comments are quite popular on YouTube. (Isn't it?)

Comment: Wow, I never would have though that 気あんの means something like きがあるの. Japanese is weird sometimes ...